# Why my 'AWS Lambda Invoke Function' task in Azure DevOps Build Pipeline doesn't fail if the Lambda returns 400?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, azure-devops

I have this python code inside Lambda:

```
#This script will run as a Lambda function on AWS.
import time, json

cmdStatus = "Failed"
message = ""
statusCode = 200

def lambda_handler(event, context):    

   time.sleep(2)

   if(cmdStatus=="Failed"):
      message = "Command execution failed"
      statusCode = 400
   elif(cmdStatus=="Success"):
      message = "The script execution is successful"
      statusCode = 200
   else:
      message = "The cmd status is: " + cmdStatus
      statusCode = 500

   return {
      'statusCode': statusCode,
      'body': json.dumps(message) 
   }
```

and I am invoking this Lambda from Azure DevOps Build Pipeline - AWS Lambda Invoke Function.

As you can see in the above code - have intentionally put that cmdStatus to Failed to make that Lambda fail but when executed from Azure DevOps Build Pipeline - the task succeeds. Strange.

How can I make the pipeline to fail in this case? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified by calling the Lambda manually via API gateway/function URL that it returns a 400? If you're synchronously invoking the lambda, there is no concept of an HTTP error for it to fail on.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the task succeeds"? (how do you see that it succeeds)

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with a similar issue myself and it looks like a bug in the task itself. It was reported in 2019 and nothing happened since so I wouldn't hold out much hope.

https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/issues/175

My workaround to this issue was to instead use the AWS CLI task with

Command: lambda
Subcommand: invoke
Options and Parameters: --function-name {nameOfYourFunction} response.json

Followed immediately by a bash task with an inline bash script

```
cat response.json

if grep -q "errorType" "response.json"; then
  echo "An error was found"
  exit 1
fi
echo "No error was found"
```